# Artemis Framework - delete all entities with a given type of component

Tags: artemis

In artemis framework how can I list all entities wtih a given type of component and delete them from the world? I couldn't find any examples in the documentation and it seems there's no straightforward way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example system that deletes all entities with the "Expires" component:

```
public class DeleteEntitiesSystem extends EntitySystem {

    public DeleteEntitiesSystem() {
        super(Aspect.getAspectForAll(Expires.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void processEntities(Array<Entity> entities) {
        for (Entity e : entities) {
            e.deleteFromWorld();
        }
    }
}
```